# Address creating function c#

Tags: c#

so, I am making a school pizza program which requests customer details such as name phone number and address. I want to make it so that the customer have to have a number, space and letter when they fill in the address, i have created a method which should error and tell the customer that their address is invalid, but this method does not seem to be working so well. Please help

Here are the codes to my current method:

```
public static string ReadAddress(String prompt) // YOU DIDN'T SPELL THIS CORRECTLY
    {
        string userInput = " ";
        bool success = false; 
        while (!success)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            try
            {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput.Length <= 70 && userInput.Length > 8) //checks the length of the user input
                {

                    success = true;     //Assumes input is correct
                    bool letter = false;
                    bool space = false;
                    bool number = false;

                    foreach (char character in userInput) 
                    {
                        letter = Char.IsLetter(character);
                        space = Char.IsWhiteSpace(character);
                        number = Char.IsNumber(character);


                    }
                    success = letter & space & number;
                }
                else
                {
                    success = false; // enables loop to exit

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return userInput;
    }
```

Currently It blocks everything even when i have a number, space and letter.

Comment: you overwrite your intermediate results in the character loop ... this way you will only find letter space and number for the last char ...

Comment: @PaulF - it's not bitwise. This isn't [tag:c]. It's the non-short-circuiting boolean `and`.

Comment: Your code would seem to accept number, space & letter in any order - if you need it to be in a specific order then you need more complex checking. Firstly only for number, only then check for space & only then check for letter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks for correcting me - I did not appreciate the distinction between & when used with int (bitwise) is different to when used with Boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've *ever* seen a letter, you want to remember that fact (ditto for the other character types).

```
 letter = letter || Char.IsLetter(character);
```

(Also, I know this check would annoy some people no end since they live in a *named* house, no numbers)

Comment: How does it work tho? letter = letter? can you explain please?

Comment: When should `letter` be `true`? It should be `true` *if it's currently true* or if the current character matches `IsLetter(character)`.

Comment: so basically letter = letter

Comment: Imma noob at c# don't know much. Sorry

Comment: @Jay - what I'm saying is that we don't want to reset `letter` to `false` if `IsLetter` returns `false` for the *current* character. You could write `if (letter==false) { letter = Char.IsLetter(character);}` but that's a lot of extra typing and is what `||` will do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could go a step further, and instead of checking each character, use regular expressions to check the pattern of the inputted string.

So to check for a number, followed by a space, and then a letter:

```
success = Regex.IsMatch(userInput, "\d [A-Z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //'IgnoreCase' means that [A-Z] matches uppercase and lowercase.
```

But that only matches against a single digit and a single letter. You can modify the pattern slightly to match a full address:

```
success = Regex.IsMatch(userInput, "\d+( [A-Z]+)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And for cases where your house may be on something like `3rd Avenue`:

```
success = Regex.IsMatch(userInput, "\d+( \w+)+");
//Don't need to ignore case anymore, since \w is a word boundary and matches any letter, and numbers.
```

Comment: Upvoted though should be the other way around - number space letter. I am guessing the OP requires multiple letters & numbers as minimum input length is 9.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like that:

```
foreach (char character in userInput) 
{
   letter |= Char.IsLetter(character);
   space |= Char.IsWhiteSpace(character);
   number |= Char.IsNumber(character);
}
```

This way you won't overwrite these flags on every character. Currently the only way for this to work would be to have last character identified as letter, whitespace and number at the same time (impossible afaik).
You can read more about this operator here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only check last your character in `for` statement! You must change your `for` statement body to this:

```
foreach (char character in userInput) 
{
   letter = letter  || Char.IsLetter(character);
   space = space || Char.IsWhiteSpace(character);
   number = number || Char.IsNumber(character);
}
```